# How can I optimize rigid body collidsions with Ogre3D and BulletPhysics

Tags: bulletphysics, ogre3d

I am developing some games with my friends, using Ogre3D and Bullet Physics.
I managed to get our game character moving (just simple run and turn).

I guess I can implement 'jumping' by this class:

```
btCollisionWorld::ClosestRayResultCallback res(btFrom, btTo);.
```

However, my big issue is collision optimization.

I tried:

1. adding 100~500 rigidbody objects (after we changed these to mapobject in our game)
2. one staticplanecollision object (ground)
3. one character rigidbody object

FPS for just moving on plane is 60~80 = ok. But when my character collides with any other rigidbody object, FPS is going down to 7.

I have no idea that fix this problem.
I am not useing `DynamicCharacterController` or `KineticCharacterController`.
Character is controlled by `setLinearVelocity()` and `rigidbody->getWorldTransform().setRotation(quat)` function

Some more information:

```
PhysicsManager::GetInstance()->getDynamicsWorld()->stepSimulation(evt.timeSinceLastFrame,8);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue before, I don't know if that's your case, but we were implementing Damned (game), and when we modeled the kitchens we were using the stoves' meshes as collision objects (btDbvtTriangleMeshShape), and everytime the character got close to a stove the FPS went down...

The solution was to use a simple collision shape for each stove (like btCompound with a few boxes), and the FPS issue went away :)

Hope your issue is similar to this so you can solve it by reducing the complexity of the collision shapes you're using.

If this isn't the case, please, show me the code you run when handling your character (also, KinematicCharacterController is highly recommended, and moving from Bullet to PhysX is even more recommended ;D).

Best.